# How do I convert Node based OpenLayers project, to using the local ol file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers, local

I have made a web application based around an OpenLayers. I installed OpenLayers through npm, and made everything work.

Due to changes in requirements (yay), i need to remove everything node related, and replace it with local files.

All examples i have been able to find (including on OpenLayers own example page), are doing it the Node way.

So far i have downloaded the dist version of OpenLayers from here: https://openlayers.org/download/

And added that file to my project.

Now i don't get how i'm supposed to replace all my imports, with calls to this file.

This is all the imports i want to replace:

```
import { Map, View } from "ol";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import WMTS from "ol/source/WMTS";
import WMTSTileGrid from "ol/tilegrid/WMTS";
import TileWMS from "ol/source/TileWMS";
import { get as getProjection } from "ol/proj";
import Projection from "ol/proj/Projection.js";
import { getTopLeft } from "ol/extent.js";
import { register } from "ol/proj/proj4.js";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add this as a normal script tag you will get a global var called `ol`..

So all you would need to do is ->

```
const { Map, View } = ol;
const TileLayer = ol.layer.Tile;
//etc..
```

Comment: Multiple imports would need to be separated, e.g. 
`const Map = ol.Map;
const View = ol.View;`

Comment: @Mike  No, you can do as I've shown.. It's called object destructoring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring, and apart from anything it keeps it a near as the OP's original.

Comment: Do i have to put it all into my html file? Right now i have my js in a seperate file, and added this to my html file: "<script href="./lib/ol/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" . This results in a "ol is not defined" error.

Comment: @AndersJensen  Just make open layers `js` files comes before your `js` file inside your HTML ..  IOW: in your html file, maybe just before the closing body tag.. put `<script src="./lib/ol/ol.js"></script><script src="mylib.js"></script>` etc.

Comment: @Keith This worked, now i just have to figure out the proper names for all my consts. Most of them i think i got through the path i used before, but a few of them are causing issues. 

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problems..  a little tip, if you `console.log(ol)` say inside Chrome, you can inspect the object, you might find some case might be different etc.

Comment: @Keith don't know why i didn't think about that. Thanks!